# Atomでコードを実行するとエラーが発生する: No module named tkinter

Tags: python, atom-editor, tkinter

Python初心者です。

```
import tkinter as tk
root= tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

IDLEで上記コードで１つ画面を出しました。Atomでキーボードのaltとrを押してこのコードを実行すると

```
No module named tkinter
```

と表示されます。atom-runnerやscriptをインストール済みです。
Atomではどうやれば実行できるか教えていただきたいです。何卒宜しくお願いします。

#### 環境

Mac、Python 3.8.2です。python3は、python公式サイトよりインストールしました。

Comment: 「Atom でコードを実行した」の部分でどのようにコードを実行したのかを教えて欲しいです。また、Python はどのようにインストールされた Python でしょうか。

Comment: こんにちは！ご返信ありがとうございます。atomでは、キーボードのaltとrを押して実行しました。python3は、python公式サイトとよりインストールしました。こちらで大丈夫でしょうか。

Comment: この記事の手順が参考になるのでは？ [PythonをAtomエディタのatom-runnerで実行する](https://remonote.jp/python-atom-runner)

Comment: nekketsuuu様本当にありがとうございましたʅ（◞‿◟）ʃできました！やっと練習にとりかかれます、本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: atomでpython3のコードを実行するところまで出来るようになりました。

今はMacのTcl/Tkという追加のソフトをインストールし、ゲームを作ろうとしています。atomでimportすると

No module named tkinter
とエラーがでます。import tkinter as tkにエラーが出ます。

python3はpython公式サイトからインストールしました。どうしたらこのエラーを解決できるでしょうか？宜しくお願いします。

Comment: この辺の記事あたりでしょうか。[import requestsでエラーが出ます](https://teratail.com/questions/122992), [macOS(Mojave)でNo module named ‘_tkinter’を解決する(pyenv , Python3.x)](https://murabitoleg.com/mac-tkinter/)

Comment: ゲームを完成させてプレイすることができました！！本当にありがとうございました^_^